# Changing Zend Server Document Root

Tags: php, apache2, zend-studio

I would have thought this one would be simple but I'm trying to change my document root from the default:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs
```

to the location where I normally keep my projects in my documents but so far I have had no luck, all I see is the "Zend Server Test Page".

I have modified the location in \Apache2\conf\httpd.conf as follows:

```
DocumentRoot "C:\Users\Me\My Sites\My Project"
<Directory "C:\Users\Me\My Sites\My Project">
```

and I have restarted php using the server GUI but to no avail.

I'm using Zend Server Community Edition 5.6.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up solving itself somehow although my best guess is that the 'Restart PHP' link on the the Zend Server Web GUI doesn't actually work, I think what I needed to do was to restart using the apache service in my system tray or restart my computer.